# libjvm.so: to link or not to link?

Tags: java, linker, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

All the guides to JNI I've seen (e. g. [JNI runtime linking](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.zos.80.doc/user/jni_libs.html)) recommend that I link my JNI libraries against `libjvm.so`:

```
$ gcc -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -c -o test.o test.c
$ gcc -shared -o libtest.so test.o -L${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/i386/server -Wl,-rpath,${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/i386/server -ljvm
```

If my custom library is written in C++ and uses the C++ JNI API, I can clearly see the corresponding weak symbols in `nm -C` output:

```
00000690 W JNIEnv_::ThrowNew(_jclass*, char const*)
00000672 W JNIEnv_::FindClass(char const*)
```

Still, if I **don't** mention `-ljvm` on the command line, the custom native library continues to work just fine, probably because `libjvm.so` gets automatically loaded by **any** Java process.

Can you tell me when it is *absolutely* necessary to explicitly link against `libjvm.so`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need it when you want it running the other way round.

For example, you want to create JVM from C/C++ code and call JVM's methods.

For example, here, we need to link with ljvm, otherwise you will not find symbols in your C code.

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo027